# Assembly printing at a certain multiple during a loop

Tags: assembly, sparc

Hi this is for Sparc Assembly Language and I have a loop with a counter to keep track of how many cycles it's looping through. How can I have it check that counter if it is multiples of 4 to print "blah blah blah" and so on. So at counts 4,8,12,16,20.....etc it should print that statement "blah blah blah". What is the most efficient way and easiest to understand since I am a beginner. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following your own example of 4... What you want, can be achieved by dividing the counter by 4 on every loop iteration. Print the message only when the remainder of that division is zero.

Since 4 is a power of 2, there is an efficient alternative, based on the fact that the rightmost (i.e. least significant) bits of *counter* (its binary representation) become `00` every four steps. Just take the bitwise 'and' of *counter* and 3 (= 4 - 1); print the message if the result is zero.

I have no Sparc experience, so here goes nothing:

```
    and  %L1,3,%g0      ; assuming register %L1 is the counter
    bne  PastMessage    ; skip the call below if result of 'and' was not zero
    call PrintMessage
PastMessage:
    ...
```